# Customize Panels in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Pretty simple question, but I can't find a solution. Is there a way to rearrange the panels/sidebars in Xcode? I prefer to have my IDE/text editor on a vertical monitor and the two sidebars in Xcode constrict the view of the actual code. I would like to be able to position these panels at the bottom of the screen rather than the sides. Thanks for the help!